# Getting whitespace in the bottom of the screen of the operamobile browser while running the jquerymobile webapplication?

Tags: jquery-ui, opera, jquery-mobile

Am developing one mobile web application using jquerymobile. i have header ,some field controls, and footer, i set the data-position ="fixed" for footer so that the footer will come bottom of the screen, i am getting this perfectly in all mobiles native browser,like safari,bb,android native. But when i running in the operamobile browser i am getting the footer in the bottom of the screen i can only seen  this footer after long scroll down and also am getting some whitespace without background color above the footer. I don't know what is this problem, is it operamobile browser compatibility   or anyother thing we have to specify in the css? has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: Try with fulscreen positioning if it appeals to you. fixed position is a bit buggy and will be fixed soon

Answer (score 0):

We saw the whitespace problem in the Android browser. Switching back from a3 to a2 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid white space at bottom in "portrait" orientation with jquerymobile 1.0b3 you should redefine "min-height" in css:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .portrait,
   .portrait .ui-page { min-height: 300px; }
</style>
```